# Passbook pkpass file not working on the simulator

Tags: ios, passbook

I followed the article [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html) to create my first Passbook pass.

```
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.mypassbook.coupon",
  "serialNumber" : "E5982H-I2",
  "teamIdentifier" : "ASDFGM5E66",
  "barcode" : {
    "message" : "123456789",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
  },
  "locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : -122.3748889,
      "latitude" : 37.6189722
    },
    {
      "longitude" : -122.03118,
      "latitude" : 37.33182
    }
  ],
  "organizationName" : "Paw Planet",
  "description" : "Coupon for a free lollipop at Example Candy Store",
  "logoText" : "Example Candy Store",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "backgroundColor" : "rgb(206, 140, 53)",
  "coupon" : {
    "primaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "offer",
        "label" : "On July 29",
        "value" : "Free lollipop"
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

In the end I created the pkpass file but when I drag and drop the file on the simulator I get the following:

[image]

Any ideas? I checked the system logs in the console app and it does not display any messages.

When I email the pkpass as an attachment to myself this is what I see. [image]

Comment: If you email me the pkpass file, I'll happily take a look and post a response. tomas@coldbear.co.uk

Comment: Sent! It says "null" in the attachment for some reason.

Comment: Here is another weird thing! When I double click on the pkpass file on my Mac then it does show the pass correctly.

Comment: The validation on OS X isn't as strict as iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the way you've signed your pass. When I open the pass on my iPhone, I get this in the logs:

*Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.azamsharp.blindscoupon/123456. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.*

Double check your certificate and values match. You must also remember to include the WWDC certificate when signing the manifest.

Comment: How are you opening on your iPhone? When I go into my Gmail app it displayed the attachment with a null ? sign on it.

Comment: I got it working! I was using the wrong TeamId. Thanks a million. Although I would love to know how you got to see the error message on console.

Comment: I'm using Xcode. The Devices view shows me the logging from the device. It's very useful with Passbook. I'm really considering building a webpage that will validate passes as it's the number #1.